# Java : remove from list elements that start with elements from other list

Tags: java

Is there a way to do something like :

```
words.removeIf(specialWords::contains);
```

But by replacing "contains" by "startWith"

Comment: What is `words`? Is it a `List<String>`?

Comment: You will need to write a lambda function that iterates through the `specialWords` and uses `startsWith` to do the test, returning `true` on a match.

Answer (score 1):

I would try the following:

```
words.removeIf(value -> specialWords.stream().anyMatch(value::startsWith));
```

This should remove every item from `words` that start with any of the `specialWords`.